# httpClient streaming with WindowsPhone not working? same code works in windows store app

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, portable-class-library, dotnet-httpclient

Is there a way to get streaming results of a response from httpClient on windowsphone?
I have the following code in a PCL targetin WP7.1+ (same problem if moving the code to the phone project iself), which works correctly running in a windowstore app, but on windows phone, the the request never chunks like it does in the store app.

once the HttpResponseMessage is available, it already has a Content-Length specified -- 0 for this data stream that is slowly filling.

I tried specifying a Connection Keep-Alive header, but on phone, specifying that header results in an ArgumentException that 'The header Connection has an empty value'.  Store app is fine with it

```
        resp = m_httpClientStream.SendAsync(request,
                HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, m_ctsStream.Token);

        resp.ContinueWith(
                (responseTask) =>
                {
                    HttpResponseMessage respMsg;
                    try
                    {
                        respMsg = responseTask.Result;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        return;
                    }

                    Task<Stream> respStream = respMsg.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                    respStream.ContinueWith(
                        async (respStreamTask) =>
                        {
                            Stream streamResp = respStreamTask.Result;

                            int read = 0;
                            do
                            {
                                byte[] responseBuffer = new byte[500];
                                read = await streamResp.ReadAsync(responseBuffer, 0, responseBuffer.Length);
                                string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBuffer, 0, read);

                                //callback
                            } while (read != 0);
                        });
               });
```

Comment: I tried upgrading the project to WP8, no change in behavior so this doesn't seem to be a WP7.x only problem.

Comment: Connnection keep alive is unnecessary.  Http 1.1 has persistent connections by default.  I don't have any suggestions for you though :-(

Answer (score 0):

In the Feb 2013 beta of httpclient, the chunked response is not supported on windows phone.  It's supposed to get added for the next public release.